# Why do Vue single file components compile to such large files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gruntjs, vue.js

I am new to Vue and Grunt/Gulp/Webpack. I got a Vue app to work fine (Grunt: browserify -> babel -> uglify) with a setup like this:

```
// app.js
const LoginComponent = require('./login.js')

// login.js
const template = `<some html>`
module.exports = Vue.component('login-component', {
    template: template,
    // component stuff
})
```

Then, in order to make my components more readable, I switched to single file components (Webpack, Grunt: babel -> uglify) and go everything to work like this:

```
// app.js
import LoginComponent from './login.js'

// login.js
<template>
    <some html>
</template>
<script>
export defalut {
    // component stuff
}
</script>
```

The problem is that when using webpack the file size is doubled. The first setup resulted in an `app.min.js` of `3.3kb`, and the second setup with webpack was `7.0kb`.

**Is this normal or did I do something wrong?**

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './resources/js/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/temp')
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Grunt btw? Standalone Webpack should be enough no?

Comment: When I used Webpack, I only used it for the import / export functionality. I have not yet seen how to use webpack to convert es6 to older js or minify js files. That's why I use Grunt, because I know it can do those things.

Comment: You can use the [babel loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) to convert es5, and the [uglify plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx), I could probably write an answer about that

Comment: Only write that answer if it also addresses my question: Why does my second method produce js files that are twice as big as the first method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your config, sometimes webpack needs to generate some runtime code that might explain the increase of your bundle size.

However you can reduce it by using the `DefinePlugin` to set the `NODE_ENV` variable to `production` and leverage the `UglifyjsWebpackPlugin`, it will result in optimized code that will most likely be smaller, so something like the following

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './resources/js/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/temp')
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production') },
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compressor: { warnings: false } }),
  ]
}
```

You can also specify the option `dead_code` to uglify so it trims out code that is never used, which might help in your case.

Also, you should get rid of Grunt entirely using the [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) and the appropriate presets.